# How to get row by integer offset from DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of `(x,y)` values which correspond to a `DataFrame`. What I want to do is this:

```
for i in range(len(X_pca)):

    pid = years_data.get_row_by_integer(i).name[0]
    person_name = persons_df.iloc[pid].forename
```

I need to be able to get an entire row, including the index values, given just the integer-offset of the row inside the `DataFrame`.

How can I do that?

I am using a multi-value index. This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you add some sample?

Comment: use `df.iterrows()`. Could you explain `given just the integer-offset of the row inside the DataFrame` ?

Comment: @jezrael What example do you need? It's basically what MMF it suggesting. I want to get a row by an integer offset.

Comment: @MMF Well, it's basically what you suggest: `[row_list.append(r) for _,r in years_data.iterrows()]`, now I can access `row_list[123]`, but can I do this directly using the `DataFrame` object?

Comment: need loops by `for i, row in df.iterrows(): print (i), print (row)`

Comment: `years_data.loc[123]` wouldn't work ? what's the type of your index ?

Comment: @MMF it's a multi-value index

Comment: can you edit your post and  add a sample value of your dataframe ?

Comment: @MMF I've added a screenshot, is that good enough?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for get position of value of `MultiIndex`:

```
X_pca = pd.DataFrame({'person':[1,2,3],
                      'year':[2010,2010,2011],
                      'a':[4,5,6]})

X_pca = X_pca.set_index(['person','year'])
print (X_pca)
             a
person year   
1      2010  4
2      2010  5
3      2011  6
```

---

```
for i, row in X_pca.iterrows(): 
    #print (i)
    #print (row) 
    print (X_pca.loc[i])
    pos = X_pca.index.get_loc(i)
    print (X_pca.iloc[pos])

a    4
Name: (1, 2010), dtype: int64
a    4
Name: (1, 2010), dtype: int64
a    5
Name: (2, 2010), dtype: int64
a    5
Name: (2, 2010), dtype: int64
a    6
Name: (3, 2011), dtype: int64
a    6
Name: (3, 2011), dtype: int64
```

If need select value of column `a`:

```
for i, row in X_pca.iterrows(): 
    #print (i)
    #print (row) 
    print (X_pca.loc[i, 'a'])
    pos = X_pca.index.get_loc(i)
    print (X_pca.iloc[pos].a)

4
4
5
5
6
6
```

Comment: Hi! Can't check it right now but I will test it tomorrow and let you know! Thank you in the meantime!